# How can I get all the ids of xml nodes via xquery?

Tags: xquery, basex

I would like to get all the ids of xml nodes via xquery

I am trying this line but does not work(returns empty characters)

```
xquery doc('MYdb/MY.xml')/ROOT/*/string(@ID)
```

the xml is like this

```
ROOT
<NODE>
<ID>CP1</ID>
<..>
</NODE>
<NODE>
<ID>CP2</ID>
<...>
</NODE>
...
</ROOT>
```

I want to receive a string like this CP1,CP2,CP3....

Comment: Please make always sure to provide working examples. `<..>` is not allowed in well-formed XML and will break your example for anybody that tries to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be

```
fn:doc("MYdb/MY.xml")//ID/fn:string()
```

because your ids are not attributes but plain elements.

The // prefix will get all ID elements from every level of your document tree

HTH

Peter